# SQL query group by interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find how to query a table with time interval.

Records are added after an event, for example one event: ten rows.
But if the same event occurs once more: ten new rows are added.
So 1 event: twenty rows.

I want to find all the events which occur more than once with id min, max and date/time

I have theese two tables :

```
First contain : ID, EVENT_TYPE, DATE, STATE
Second contain : ID, EVENT_NUMBER, DATA_OF_EVENT
```

So I want two result rows if event occurs 2 times

Sample data:

```
-----------
| TABLE1   |
-----------
1, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
2, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
3, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
4, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
5, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
6, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
7, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
8, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
9, T1, 20141031 10:00:00
10, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
11, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
12, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
13, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
14, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
15, T1, 20141031 10:20:00
16, T2, 20141101 09:10:00
17, T1, 20141101 15:52:00

-----------
| TABLE2   |
-----------
1, EVENT1, Some data...
2, EVENT1, Some data...
3, EVENT1, Some data...
4, EVENT1, Some data...
5, EVENT1, Some data...
6, EVENT1, Some data...
7, EVENT1, Some data...
8, EVENT1, Some data...
9, EVENT1, Some data...
10, EVENT1, Some data...
11, EVENT1, Some data...
12, EVENT1, Some data...
13, EVENT1, Some data...
14, EVENT1, Some data...
15, EVENT1, Some data...
16, EVENT2, Some data...
17, EVENT3, Some data...

------------------
| Wanted result   |
------------------
EVENT1, 1, 9, 20141031 10:00:00
EVENT1, 10, 15, 20141031 10:20:00
```

Comment: add some data sample and preferably some DDL or SQLFiddle.com

Comment: Why are you adding 10 duplicate rows to `TABLE1` ? I do not see any difference between them except of ID, which seems to be auto-increment.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to new request:

```
select a.event_number, b.min_id, b.max_id, cast(b.date as smalldatetime)
from table2 a inner join 
(select min(id) min_id, max(id) max_id, cast(date as smalldatetime) date, event_type
from table1
group by cast(date as smalldatetime), event_type) b
on a.id=b.min_id
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ms182418.aspx)

> ss is two digits, ranging from 00 to 59, that represent the second.
>   Values that are 29.998 seconds or less are rounded down to the nearest
>   minute, Values of 29.999 seconds or more are rounded up to the nearest
>   minute.

[TEST in SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/308bc/2)

Comment: Yes !! But just one more details.
Sometimes the datetime have a few seconds to a single record.
How datetime group with a tolerance of 1 minutes?

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE one minute time spam or within same minute disregarding seconds? ie, 10:10:10 vs 10:11:09 case 1: in tolerance, case 2: not in tolerance

Comment: Yes with disregarding second, but if xx:10:58 the minute change :(

Comment: @BenjaminCEREDE Have you tried this? Do you know haw to formally accept an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/tour